# I corrupted OneDrive for all my coworkers

Tags: powershell, onedrive, reparsepoint

I wanted to backup my OneDrive for Business folder to an external HD (I use Veeam) and that has not been possible for a while, after some update by Microsoft.
This morning I did some research and I stumbled upon this: https://forum.acronis.com/comment/451003#comment-451003

I dumbly, blindly followed the advice and typed:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
fsutil reparsepoint delete $file.FullName
}
```

into the Powershell, from the OneDrive folder.
After execution, I tried to backup *some* files and it worked. (Note that due to this, I have today's backup for just some of the files)
Yay, I thought.

However, after a few hours, my changes had propagated and my coworkers were unable to open DOCX and XLSX files. All of them. "Cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid". 
"Open and Repair" from inside Office not working.
Restoring yesterday's OneDrive not working (files were overwritten with same name). 
Microsoft helpdesk will contact us back.

Help! We have an old backup but we cannot afford to lose 2 weeks' work! Is there any way to undo the reparsepoint thing, or to recover the corrupt Office files?

Comment: That sucks hard, dude

Comment: OneDrive to where - cloud or on-premises? Restoring yesterday's - how? Where from? From Veeam or from something else? Do any of the computers have Previous Versions enabled on their hard disks, which might be able to get the files from a previous day?